# MYSQL count with double condition

Tags: mysql, count, subquery, where-clause

I need count the cc column. in the way that the result will this with only 2 rows.
first row. the quantity of people that have premio_id = 0 and
the second row, the quantity of people that have premio_id different to 0. thanks all.

simulation of result.

```
| quantity_people | premio type     |
|    3000         |     0           |
|    25231        | different to  0 |
```

Table:

[image: table data]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select sum(cc) as quantity_people,
(case premio_id when 0 then '0' else 'different to 0' end) as premio_type
from your_table_name
group by (case premio_id when 0 then '0' else 'different to 0' end);
```

Comment: Do you need the count of cc column or the sum of the values in it?

Comment: thank you. the solution is the correct.